# Can't get @media queries to work when overriding bootstrap 4 using React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

Basically, using bootstrap 4, i'm trying to take the bootstrap class "custom-select" and override some of the bootstrap elements for my own uses. Here's the html and scss im using. Pretty simple stuff imo.

```
<select className="custom-select" id='sortingSelect' onChange={(e) => setSortingOption(e.target.value)}>
                    <option defaultValue value ="0">Random</option> 
                    <option value="1">A - Z</option>
                    <option value="2">Z - A</option>
                </select>


.custom-select#sortingSelect{
    width: 5% !important;
    float: right !important;
    margin-right:5% !important;
}
```

It straight up would not work when i put it in the "module.scss" for that page i was working on, so i ended up having to put it into my custom.scss that globally overrides stuff. Even when using !important tags, it still wouldn't work in my module.scss, but it does work with my custom.scss. That's problem solved, well, kind of.

Because! I want it to also be able to change with screen size, this is bootstrap after all. So i put the following into my custom.scss

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
.custom-select#sortingSelect{
    float: none !important;
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

}

It doesn't even seem to recognize this input at all for some reason :/

Are media queries simply just not allowed in the custom.scss file? If that's the case am i just boned? Or am i just going about this all wrong? It could be some issue with specificity, but how the heck do i get more specific than what ive already got?

Please lemme know if i need to provide more context!

Also! I read that i need to include the following code in my html

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
```

However, i am using React, so i included it in the html that is returned from my Layout component that renders everything else, still no luck, and that wouldn't make sense as the problem anyhow, because media queries have worked before in that very same file, just not with overriding bootstrap stuff. Overriding bootstrap stuff always seems to be way more difficult than it needs to be in my experience so far.

Edit: I tried using bootstraps built in break points, but that failed as well

Answer (score 0):

### Why are you using both class and ID at the same time in your CSS file.

Either use className or Id for CSS.

---

**Like:**

```
.custom-select{
    width: 5% !important;
    float: right !important;
    margin-right:5% !important;
}
```

**OR**

```
#sortingSelect{
    Height: 5% !important;
    float: left !important;
    margin-left: 5% !important;
}
```